# Getting Queued Jobs response Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

currently I have the following set up, a route that is calling a function in my controller that is in turn queuing a job.

//My Route

`Route::get('/testJob', 'Controller@testJob');`

//My Controller

```
public function testJob()
{
    $job = (new testJob())->delay(5);
    $this->dispatch($job);
}
```

//My job

```
public function handle()
{   
    require 'testAPICall.php';
    // echo $response;
    return $response;
}
```

//testAPICall.php

```
$response = 'this is the response';
```

//Queue After

```
Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
    echo var_dump($event->data);
});
```

What I would like to be able to do, is access the response returned by the job in Queue::after, or alternatively, pass a callback into the queue to be execute after the job, again with access to the response from the job.

Is this something that is possible with Laravel Queues, and if so how would I go about this?

Cheers, Jack.

Comment: not commenting on your question but you should not require php files like you did so, create classes for the same (just saying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queue::after() is a global callback, that will run after each job. So this might not what you want.
In your case, I would depend on Events/Listeners to be triggered after finishing the job.

```
public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
{
   //Your code 
   event(new JobDone($data));
}
```

Please let me know if you need more details for implementation.

Comment: Thanks for that, using events I was able to solve the problem at hand

Comment: glad to hear, that's great.

Comment: @JackDavies How exactly did you solve it? Were you able to somehow access the response from the job in the main application (as opposed to in the queue worker)?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski sorry it's be so long I have no idea what I done exactly other than than look into using events

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like yours that log a message "queue.txt" in laravel 5 "app" folder

This code I've got from a youtube video and not my code , but I have tested it successfully

First thing you have to code in "Routes.php" as below

```
Route::get('/',function()
 {
   //$queue = Queue::push('LogMessage',array('message'=>'Time: '.time()));
   $queue = Queue::later(20,'LogMessage',array('message'=>'Time: '.time()));
   return $queue; 
 });

class LogMessage{
  public function fire($job,$data){
    File::append(app_path().'/queue.txt',$data['message'].PHP_EOL);
     $job->delete(); 
   }
}
```

Then you can run your project folder using *"php -S localhost:8888 -t public"*

at the same time you must open a another terminal window in windows or linux environment and pointed to same folder and issue the command *"php artisan queue:listen"*

I think this will be helpful for you!

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Wasn't really what I was after but others might find it useful.

Comment: @JackDavies Thank you!